# Trying to fetch documents that aren't equal to a users own UID

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a profile discovery feature similar to Tinder, which only shows one profile at a time and allows you to connect/skip.

Currently, I'm fetching one document at a time from my profile database, then displaying that document in a ForEach loop:

```
   ForEach(discoverList, id: \.uuid) { profile in
            DiscoveryCardView(discoveryProfile: profile)
     }
```

This works fine.

However, I have an if statement in place to check whether the fetched document's uid is equal to the users own uid, and if it is, it wont be added to the fetched list in the view.

The code for that:

```
func fetchCards {

FirebaseService.shared.fetchInitialCards(document: document) { documents, error in
    guard let documents = documents else {return}
    
    var list: [DiscoveryProfileModel] = []

    for doc in documents {
        
        let profile = DiscoveryProfileModel(doc.data())
        
        if !profile.bookmarks.contains(Constants.myUid) && !profile.createdBy.isEqualTomyUid {
                list.append(profile)
            }
    }
}
}
```

and this is the FirebaseService.shared.fetchInitialCards function:

```
 db.collection(FIRCollections.DiscoveryProfiles.rawValue)
            .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
            .limit(to: 1)
            .start(afterDocument: lastDoc)
            .getDocuments { snapshot, error in
                
                guard let snapshot = snapshot else {return}
                
                let documents = snapshot.documents
                
                completion(documents, error)
            }
```

Because there is a 1 document limit on the profile fetch, it returns an empty array if the fetched document is equal to the user's own UID.

Is there any way around this? Can I directly fetch documents that aren't equal to the users own id from the get documents function, similar to ".wherefield", instead of after the fact? let me know.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal_? But you won't be able to combine that with the `order(by:` clause that you have.